# Can I obtain the AWS public certificate programatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, certificate, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a Lambda for an API Gateway Authorizer that validates that certain information is generated in an EC2 instance. To do this, I'm using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html but I'm wondering what the best way to keep track of the AWS public certificate is. Of course, I can just save the current certificate in a file and when it changes things will start failing, but ideally I'd like to get it dynamically from a URL so I don't have to release a new version with the updated certificate. Is there a URL I can get the certificate from? I've searched the AWS documentation (including KMS just in case) but found nothing...

Comment: Has the certificate *ever* changed?

Answer (score 0):

Store the signature in an S3 bucket.

Retrieve the file from S3 as needed (cache locally if you want).

If the public key changes, just update the file in S3.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my question, that's what I'm doing at the moment and trying to avoid. The idea is to download it from somewhere that's managed by AWS so the moment they update it my lambda will keep working.

Comment: The signatures are not located at a public/known URL. If they were, one would think the documentation you reference would mention it. By putting the files in S3, you don't have to "release a new version".

Comment: If the certificate is not publicly available, I guess it'll have to be done that way. I was just hoping someone would point me to a URL I may have been missing... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/get-certificate.html

Where it returns:

> MIICiTCCAfICCQD6m7oRw0uXOjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBiDELMAkGA1UEBhMC
>   VVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAldBMRAwDgYDVQQHEwdTZWF0dGxlMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZBbWF6
>   b24xFDASBgNVBAsTC0lBTSBDb25zb2xlMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlUZXN0Q2lsYWMxHzAd
>   BgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEG5vb25lQGFtYXpvbi5jb20wHhcNMTEwNDI1MjA0NTIxWhcN
>   MTIwNDI0MjA0NTIxWjCBiDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAldBMRAwDgYD
>   VQQHEwdTZWF0dGxlMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZBbWF6b24xFDASBgNVBAsTC0lBTSBDb25z
>   b2xlMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlUZXN0Q2lsYWMxHzAdBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEG5vb25lQGFt
>   YXpvbi5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMaK0dn+a4GmWIWJ
>   21uUSfwfEvySWtC2XADZ4nB+BLYgVIk60CpiwsZ3G93vUEIO3IyNoH/f0wYK8m9T
>   rDHudUZg3qX4waLG5M43q7Wgc/MbQITxOUSQv7c7ugFFDzQGBzZswY6786m86gpE
>   Ibb3OhjZnzcvQAaRHhdlQWIMm2nrAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAtCu4
>   nUhVVxYUntneD9+h8Mg9q6q+auNKyExzyLwaxlAoo7TJHidbtS4J5iNmZgXL0Fkb
>   FFBjvSfpJIlJ00zbhNYS5f6GuoEDmFJl0ZxBHjJnyp378OD8uTs7fLvjx79LjSTb
>   NYiytVbZPQUQ5Yaxu2jXnimvw3rrszlaEXAMPLE=

Comment: No, I mean the public certificate for all public regions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html

If there was an ARN for that certificate and I could use `get-certificate` to get it it'd be grand.